# Is it possible to proxy a POJO in microservices application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I would like to avoid duplicating my POJOs in a microservices application, so I am wondering if there is a way to do that (like proxying)?

I mean, is there a way for a `Service A` to access POJOs (or other classes/interfaces) defined inside a `Service B` without physically creating these POJOs classe files in `Service A`?

The big big challenge in a microservice architecture is that point and I didn't find a way to solve it.

Comment: I also appreciate the quick answer :-)

Comment: I am at 165 rep today ... so only 35 missing to hit the daily limit today. I am always extra quick in such situations ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Simple": when there are two services that should be using something **common** - then the answer is move this code into some form of *library* and have both services depend on it.

Anything else is most likely a *bad* idea. The whole idea of micro-services is that service A does *not* in any form depend on B. And you do **not** want to get into the reflection game and somehow access internals of another service through some sort of backdoor.

As some comment makes clear: using a library helps to avoid *code duplication*. The alternative is to **willfully** copy the "common" parts from service B into service A. This is an option, too.

In that sense: you either re-factor the common parts into a library - or you copy them. Both approaches have their pros and cons. You have to determine what matters most in your environment.

Comment: Not necessarily. Version control for service is a different topic. You would only need to redeploy when *that* service wants to exploit new features in the library!

Comment: I agree with @GhostCat. You can have a strategy to handle this :
If you have a new field then service A doesn't need to know about the new field. however, if you want to remove a field you'd better deprecate it.

Comment: I suggest to copy the code, so that the services can develop independently. By using a library you avoid code duplication, at the cost of tighter coupling/dependencies.

Comment: @akuma8 if you need to update the code your way you probably need to deploy both services as well if its a breaking change. A decent way to split projects is to have core / common, client, server all in the same repo for the same service. Service A interacts with Service B with Service B's client. You can deploy Service B without deploying Service A as long as its a backwards compatible change.

Comment: I prefer the versionning library approch with a common repo as suggested @BillO'Neil

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this rule of thumb:**

For **enterprise** applications and **complex** objects, create a 3'rd project (an API project), and share it among your services as a dependency.

For **simple** and **self-descriptive** objects, use 'copies' of the same objects in each one of your services; note that this is powerful since the POJOs don't need to be identical;

For instance:

In one service (A), it can look like this:

```
@Entity
public class ExchangeValue {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "currency_from")
    private String from;

    @Column(name = "currency_to")
    private String to;

    @Column(name = "conversion_multiple")
    private BigDecimal conversionMultiple;
    ...
}
```

wheres in another service (B) it can be much shorter, and with different types:

```
public class ExchangeValue {
    private int conversionMultiple;
    ...
}
```