# Microservices shared objects

Tags: java, shared-libraries, messaging, microservices, dry

Currently we are building a microservice oriented application from our monolith.

The issue we are facing is how to send and receive objects between services while keeping the services independent.

Problem:
Say we have an EventService and a NotificationService. The EventService generates an Event, serializes it (json/java?) and publishes the serialized object on an ActiveMQ topic.
The NotificationService, which is listening to that specific topic, receives the serialized object and has to deserialize it and therefore needs to know the Event-Class.

What is a good approach to solve the problem of sharing the Event-Class between the two services?
Should I introduce a new Project which contains only the Event-Class? The Problem I see here is that this could lead to two scenarios:

1. The shared project gets bloated up and will contain more classes than each service including it will need.
2. I will have an extra project for every two services that share some type of objects which results in a massive overhead with a growing number of services.

Comment: 'microservice religion' says no dependencies, so one side can produce for example more fields in newer version (and this lead text format serialisation). Personally for me, You idea is good, third project I can name 'Protocols' or 'ProtocolXyz' (and this violates ms religion). Question: Both ms will be developed by independent groups? ("two pizza team") Monoliths are not totally evil

Comment: You could share an API, mainly containing POJOs, between your microservices, which would help with the serialization/deserialization process in and out of your ActiveMQ topic

Comment: Each service will have it's own interpretation of what the content of the JSON means. Therefore, they will have their own relevant objects. If the contents of the JSON (I.E. the Event) have similar meanings between services, then I would suggest that the coupling is too tight from the design level.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, we are not building in different teams yet, since our application is too monolithic. I think the API approach will lead to similar problems I described above. @jr593 that also came to my mind while thinking about solutions, but the more I dig into that direction, the more I see another monolith arising.

Answer (score 1):

**Follow this rule of thumb:**

For **enterprise** applications and **complex** objects, create a 3'rd project (an API project), and share it among your services as a dependency.

For **simple** and **self-descriptive** objects, use 'copies' of the same objects in each one of your services; note that this is powerful since the POJOs don't need to be identical;

I just shared sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033483/6792588)